# Image Loader with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In my main page, I'm calling an AsyncTask that is its own class.

```
new DownloadFileAsync(context, icon, resultp.get(PublicProfilePage.REVIEWCREATORFBOOKID),"300").execute();
```

Below is my AsyncTask. I'm reading a JSON trying to get the image's URL. Once I capture that URL I use ImageLoader to cache it, but it does not work.

```
public class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

//private Context context;
CircularImageView bmImage;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
String fbook_id;
String jsonobject;
String image_size;
String size_url;

public DownloadFileAsync(Context context, CircularImageView bmImage, String fbook_id, String size) 
{
//this.context = context;
this.bmImage = bmImage;
this.fbook_id = fbook_id;
this.image_size = size;

//Image Loader Initialization
imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);

if(image_size.equalsIgnoreCase("150")) {
    size_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/" + fbook_id + "/picture?redirect=0&height=150&width=150";
}else if(image_size.equalsIgnoreCase("300")) {
    size_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/" + fbook_id + "/picture?redirect=0&height=300&width=300";
}
}


protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
    String result = null;
    String queryResponse = null;
    String resultTwo = null;

        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclientBankCheck = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httppostBankCheck = new HttpGet(size_url);

        try {
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse responseBankCheck = httpclientBankCheck.execute(httppostBankCheck);
            HttpEntity responseText = responseBankCheck.getEntity();
            queryResponse = EntityUtils.toString(responseText);             

            // Retrive JSON Objects from the given website URL in
            // JSONfunctions.class
            jsonobject = queryResponse;

            // Locate the array name
            JSONObject arr = new JSONObject(jsonobject);

            result = arr.getString("data");

            JSONObject arrTwo = new JSONObject(result);

            resultTwo = arrTwo.getString("url");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    return resultTwo;

}

protected void onPostExecute(String resultTwo) {
    //bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultTwo, bmImage);

}



}
```

If I hard code the URL into ImageLoader inside my main page, it does work. Is the problem that I'm using an AsyncTask with ImageLoader? It shouldn't be right?

Really appreciate the help!

-M

Comment: Are you sure your json response is correct and you aren't hitting any of your catches?

Comment: Use Glide or Picasso to do it..

Comment: Json returns exactly what I want to return. This method should work and it is working, but not when I call it from a different class.